# RuntimeManager.BindLicense x64 problem

Tags: arcgis-server, license, 64bit

I am using ArcGIS server and I have an issue with `RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ProductCode.Server)` on x64 configuration (dll file name is "*ESRI.ArcGIS.Version.dll*"), the execution process exits without the possibility to catch an exception. The same `BindLicense` works perfectly OK on x86 configuration, however this configuration is not suitable because x64 dlls cannot be loaded. My colleagues do not have this issue with x64 configuration, and we could not find any differences yet which could cause this issue. ArcGIS server manager is running fine, I can see it in the web. Any ideas what might be wrong and how to solve this issue? If it is of any help here is the short version of the [dumpfile_results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48163342/WinDbg_Results.txt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that it was purely Visual Studio 2015 problem, I've identified it when launched the application directly from Windows explorer (without Visual Studio) - the problem did not show up. After repairing Visual Studio the problem is gone.